# How to update the user data instantly in my application?

Tags: android, json, sdk, sharedpreferences, android-volley

I am making an application which has a profile section for user data. Where a person can update the data such as college, university, branch. I have saved this data in shared preference when the person logged in the application and from that shared preference data, all the information of a user has been provided. How to instantly change the preferences data and set to the whole app. Well I am new in developing field os need help in getting things done.

Here is my code for updating user data activity

```
  public void edit_user_data(){



    final String str_new_name = _edit_prof_name_.getText().toString().trim();

    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ObjectAnimator flip = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imgSpoon, "rotationY", 0f, 180f);
    flip.setDuration(800);
    flip.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    flip.start();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URLconstant.USER_UPDATE, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            try {
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONObject updatedata = data.optJSONObject("data");
                int intError = updatedata.getInt("status");
                boolean error = (intError > 0) ? true : false;
                if(intError == 1){
                    String msg = updatedata.optString("msg");
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityUserEditProfile.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    JSONArray data_array = new JSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0;i<=data_array.length();i++){
                        JSONObject data_obj = data_array.getJSONObject(i);
                     /*   UserProfileData  userdata = new UserProfileData();
                        userdata.setFullname(data_obj.getString("fullname"));
                        userdata.setUniverId(data_obj.getString("univer_id"));
                        userdata.setMuniversity(data_obj.getString("university"));
                        userdata.setCollegeid(data_obj.getString("collegeid"));
                        userdata.setMcollege(data_obj.getString("college"));
                        userdata.setBranchid(data_obj.getString("branchid"));
                        userdata.setMbranch(data_obj.getString("branch"));
                        userdata.setSemid(data_obj.getString("semid"));
                        userdata.setMsemester(data_obj.getString("semester"));
                        userdata.setUserImage(data_obj.getString("user_image"));
                        userdata.setUserId(data_obj.getString("user_id"));
                        userdata.setPassword(data_obj.getString("password"));
                        updated_info(data_obj);

                        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PRE_LOGIN_REGISTRATION, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                       *//* preferences.edit().remove(FULL_NAME);
                        preferences.edit().remove(UNIVER_ID);
                        preferences.edit().remove(BRANCH_ID);
                        preferences.edit().remove(COLLEGE_ID);
                        preferences.edit().remove(SEM_ID);*//*
                        editor.clear();
                        editor.commit();

                        PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper = new PreferenceHelper();
                        preferenceHelper.getInstance(context).setBranchid(userdata.getBranchid());
                        preferenceHelper.getInstance(context).setCollegeid(userdata.getCollegeid());
                        preferenceHelper.getInstance(context).setEnrollno(userdata.getEnrollno());
                        preferenceHelper.getInstance(context).setFullname(userdata.getFullname());
                        preferenceHelper.getInstance(context).setMobile(userdata.getMobile());
                        preferenceHelper.getInstance(context).setSemid(userdata.getSemid());
                        preferenceHelper.getInstance(context).setUniverId(userdata.getUniverId());
                        preferenceHelper.getInstance(context).setUserId(userdata.getUserId());
                        preferenceHelper.getInstance(context).setUserImage(userdata.getUserImage());
                        preferenceHelper.getInstance(context).setMuniversity(userdata.getMuniversity());
                        preferenceHelper.getInstance(context).setMcollege(userdata.getMcollege());
                        preferenceHelper.getInstance(context).setMbranch(userdata.getMbranch());
                        preferenceHelper.getInstance(context).setMsemester(userdata.getMsemester());
                        preferenceHelper.getInstance(context).setPassword(userdata.getPassword());*/





                    }
                }else{
                    String msg = updatedata.optString("msg");
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityUserEditProfile.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          //  pDialog.hide();
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }){
        //adding parameters to the request
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("fullname",str_new_name);
            params.put("univer_id",u_id);
            params.put("collegeid",c_id);
            params.put("branchid",b_id);
            params.put("semid",s_id);
            params.put("mobile",PreferenceHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getMobile());
            return params;
        }
    };

    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(strReq);

}
```

Comment: Be more clear, do u use sharedPreferences or som other persistent storage? what do u want

Comment: yes, I am using shared preferences to store data. what I want is the way we update our user profile in any application such as Flipkart, paytm, watsapp . the data got updated instantly that I want to know how I can update data in my application  like the way other application updating

Comment: @Deepak, As per my understanding you want to update whole app data so that it reflect instantly, if yes, can you follow these link- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Listening.

Answer (score 0):

For this You can do this

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener spChanged = new
                       SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
    // your stuff here
}
```

};

For Details can you follow this  [android developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Listening)